# How to create a \pagenumbering style?

Tags: page-numbering, counters, customize, hindi, custom

I want to create a `\pagenumbering` style using devanagari alphabets only for `\frontmatter`.
here is an example which I want to create:

```
i -> अ
ii -> आ
iii -> इ 
iv -> ई
v -> उ
vi -> ऊ
```

etc.
P.S. This is a natural order for Hindi/Sanskrit alphabets using devanagari script.

I created an sty file as:

```
% varnamala.sty

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{varnamala}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

% Define your custom symbols here
\newcommand{\customPageSymbol}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1% 0
  \or अ% 1
  \or आ% 2
  \or इ% 3
  \or ई% 4
  \or उ% 5
  \or ऊ% 6
  \or ऋ% 7
  \or ॠ% 8
  \or ऌ% 9
  \or ॡ% 10
  \or ए% 11
  \or ऐ% 12
  \or ओ% 13
  \or औ% 14
  \or क्% 15
  \or ख्% 16
  \else *\textbf{?}*% for numbers greater than 16
  \fi%
}
```

Here is the tex file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Sahadeva} % Replace with the actual font name
\usepackage{varnamala}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\customPageSymbol{\arabic{page}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{my title}
\maketitle

\chapter{प्रस्तावना}

यह एक हिंदी किताब की प्रस्तावना है।
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{1}

\end{document}
```

I did some work and now it works fine but if I remove `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\customPageSymbol{\arabic{page}}}` line from main tex file I am not able to see the devanagari varnamala, instead I see roman numerals.

The question completely changes now to "how to add this command directly to sty file so that it works?"

P.S. Here I used a custom font [FROM THIS LINK](https://bombay.indology.info/software/fonts/devanagari/index.html)

Comment: Please add a full example of a document, not just the `.sty` file. It is possible that something in your `.tex` file that comes after this `.sty` is overriding it, for example.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\customPageSymbol{\arabic{page}}}`  is wrong ,it should be `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\customPageSymbol{\value{page}}}` or better define it as in my answer, `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\customSymbol{page}}`

Comment: there is no question here to answer now. obviously `\thepage` produces arabic numeral until you redefine it, so`but if I remove \renewcommand{\thepage}{\customPageSymbol{\arabic{page}}} line from main tex file I am not able to see the devanagari varnamala, instead I see roman numerals.` is expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\thepage` is not always a number that can be used with `\ifcase`, it might be `i`, `ii`, or `1 of 32` depending on the current style.

The latex convention is to define a `\@...` style taking a number, eg `\@roman`, and a document command taking a counter name, eg `\roman`.

So:

```
\newcommand{\@devnum}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1% 0
  \or अ% 1
  \or आ% 2
  \or इ% 3
  \or ई% 4
  \or उ% 5
  \else *\textbf{?}*% for numbers greater than 5
  \fi%
}
\newcommand{\devnum}[1]{\@devnum{\value{#1}}
```

Then you can use

```
\fancypagestyle{customstyle}{%%
  \fancyhf{}%%  % Clear all headers and footers
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%%  % Remove header line
  \fancyfoot[C]{\devnum{page} (\roman{page})}  % Custom symbol in the center of the footer
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. I changed the question. Can you please take a look into that?

Comment: @LoveGrover there is no question in your edited post but you should define the command as I show here (not necessarily with the name I used)